# How to login to Gmail using MailServerConnect[ ]?

Tags: external-calls, email

I am trying to login to my Gmail account using the built-in function `MailServerConnect[]` and require help with the process:

---

1. Connecting to the Gmail server (using `MailServerConnect[]`)

I know Mathematica added `MailServerConnect` in version 12 but when I tried it as

```
MailServerConnect["mail.google.com", "username", "pass"]
```

, this message appears:

```
MailServerConnect::auth: Failed to connect to mail.google.com port 993: Connection refused
```

**Question** What is the reason for the appearance of this message? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try: smtp.gmail.com ?

Comment: it returns: `Failed to connect to smtp.google.com port 993: Timed out`

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-check-that-imap-is-turned-on

Comment: For incoming connections to gmail, use the server: imap.gmail.com. I tried and was [denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qcRV.png) access with an ominous red-themed message that someone has my password. Also you have to enable [IMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMyVJ.png) on gmail settings.

Comment: @Syed thanks but it already was enabled for me!

Comment: So can you or can you not use the imap server to log in now?

Comment: returns this: `MailServerConnect::auth: Login denied` can you connect to your email?

Comment: On the support page included above, search for "less secure app access" and make sure your account will receive such connections. Also log into your account through a browser, and there will be a google critical alert message in your inbox. Making progress ... Until I create another account, I don't want to mess up my main account, so I will not be pursuing this further. If you are similarly unsure, create another account for experimentation.

Comment: @Syed Thanks a lot. it worked! Please add your instruction as a answer. Please add your suggestions for 2-4 steps. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it worked!! Please edit your post including title and make it about "logging in" only. Then start a fresh and a more focused question when you run into difficulty with next steps. Let this be the last comment on the page.